# In akka streaming program w/ Source.queue & Sink.queue I offer 1000 items, but it just hangs when I try to get 'em out

Tags: scala, queue, akka, streaming

I am trying to understand how i should be working with Source.queue & Sink.queue in Akka streaming.
In the little test program that I wrote below I find that I am able to successfully offer 1000 items to the Source.queue.
However, when i wait on the future that should give me the results of pulling  all those items off the queue, my 
future never completes.    Specifically, the message 'print what we pulled off the queue' that we should see at the end
never prints out -- instead we see the error  "TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]"

any guidance greatly appreciated !

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.event.{Logging, LoggingAdapter}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Keep, Sink, Source}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, Attributes}
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

import scala.collection.immutable
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}

class StreamSpec extends FunSuite {
  implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val log: LoggingAdapter = Logging(actorSystem.eventStream, "basis-test")
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher

  case class Req(name: String)
  case class Response(
                       httpVersion: String = "",
                       method: String = "",
                       url: String = "",
                       headers: Map[String, String] = Map())


  test("put items on queue then take them off") {
    val source = Source.queue[String](128, akka.stream.OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
    val flow = Flow[String].map(element => s"Modified $element")
    val sink = Sink.queue[String]().withAttributes( Attributes.inputBuffer(128, 128))

    val (sourceQueue, sinkQueue) = source.via(flow).toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()

    (1 to 1000).map( i =>
      Future {
        println("offerd" + i)             // I see this print 1000 times as expected
        sourceQueue.offer(s"batch-$i")
      }
    )
    println("DONE OFFER FUTURE FIRING")

    // Now use the Sink.queue to pull the items we added onto the Source.queue
    val seqOfFutures: immutable.Seq[Future[Option[String]]] = 
        (1 to 1000).map{ i => sinkQueue.pull() }
    val futureOfSeq: Future[immutable.Seq[Option[String]]] = 
        Future.sequence(seqOfFutures)
    val seq: immutable.Seq[Option[String]] = 
        Await.result(futureOfSeq, 10.second)
    // unfortunately our future times out here
    println("print what we pulled off the queue:" + seq);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looking again and taking a guess: maybe i'm causing deadlock by firing off so many futures. will try to do with fewer futures.

Comment: Looking yet again, perhaps this is not the best way to simulate what my load will be in production. I won't have one thread just putting things on the queue and another separate thread taking things off.   Rather, i will have some number of inflight threads, each of which puts some work on the queue, then attempts to pull some work off the queue and move that to the next step (potentially blocking).  I will work on simulating that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this again, I realize that I originally set up and posed my question incorrectly.

The test that accompanies my original question launches a wave 
of 1000 futures, each of which tries to offer 1 item to the queue. 
Then the second step in that test attempts create a 1000-element sequence (seqOfFutures) 
where each future is trying to pull a value from the queue.
My theory as to why I was  getting time-out errors is that there was some kind of deadlock due to running 
out of threads or due to  one thread  waiting on another but where the waited-on-thread was blocked, 
or something like that.

I'm not interested in hunting down the exact cause at this point because I have corrected 
things in the code below (see CORRECTED CODE).

In the new code the test that uses the queue is called:
"put items on queue then take them off (with async parallelism) - (3)".

In this test I have a set of 10 tasks which run  in parallel to do the 'enequeue' operation.
Then I have another 10 tasks which do the dequeue operation, which involves not only taking
the item off the list, but also calling stringModifyFunc which introduces a 1 ms processing delay.

I also wanted  to prove that I got some performance benefit from 
launching tasks in parallel and having the task steps communicate by passing their results through a 
queue, so test 3 runs as a timed operation, and I found that it takes 1.9 seconds.

Tests (1) and (2) do the same amount of work, but serially -- The first with no intervening queue, and the second
using the queue to pass results between steps. These tests run in 13.6 and 15.6 seconds respectively
(which shows that the queue adds a bit of overhead, but that this is overshadowed by the efficiencies of running tasks in parallel.)

**CORRECTED CODE**

```
import akka.{Done, NotUsed}
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.event.{Logging, LoggingAdapter}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Keep, Sink, Source}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, Attributes, QueueOfferResult}
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}

class Speco extends FunSuite {
  implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val log: LoggingAdapter = Logging(actorSystem.eventStream, "basis-test")
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher

  val stringModifyFunc: String => String = element => {
    Thread.sleep(1)
    s"Modified $element"
  }

  def setup = {
    val source = Source.queue[String](128, akka.stream.OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
    val sink = Sink.queue[String]().withAttributes(Attributes.inputBuffer(128, 128))
    val (sourceQueue, sinkQueue) = source.toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()
    val offers: Source[String, NotUsed] = Source(
      (1 to iterations).map { i =>
        s"item-$i"
      }
    )
    (sourceQueue,sinkQueue,offers)
  }

  val outer = 10
  val inner = 1000
  val iterations = outer * inner

  def timedOperation[T](block : => T) = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result: T = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) / (1000 * 1000) + " milliseconds")
    result
  }

  test("20k iterations in single threaded loop no queue (1)") {
    timedOperation{
      (1 to iterations).foreach { i =>
        val str = stringModifyFunc(s"tag-${i.toString}")
        System.out.println("str:" + str);
      }
    }
  }

  test("20k iterations in single threaded loop with queue (2)") {
    timedOperation{
      val (sourceQueue, sinkQueue, offers) = setup
      val resultFuture: Future[Done] = offers.runForeach{ str =>
        val itemFuture = for {
          _ <- sourceQueue.offer(str)
          item <- sinkQueue.pull()

        } yield (stringModifyFunc(item.getOrElse("failed")) )
        val item = Await.result(itemFuture, 10.second)
        System.out.println("item:" + item);
      }

      val  result = Await.result(resultFuture, 20.second)
      System.out.println("result:" + result);
    }
  }

  test("put items on queue then take them off (with async parallelism) - (3)") {
    timedOperation{
      val (sourceQueue, sinkQueue, offers) = setup

      def enqueue(str: String) = sourceQueue.offer(str)
      def dequeue = {
        sinkQueue.pull().map{
          maybeStr =>
            val str =    stringModifyFunc( maybeStr.getOrElse("failed2"))
            println(s"dequeud value is $str")

        }
      }

      val offerResults: Source[QueueOfferResult, NotUsed] =
        offers.mapAsyncUnordered(10){ string => enqueue(string)}
      val dequeueResults: Source[Unit, NotUsed] = offerResults.mapAsyncUnordered(10){ _ =>  dequeue }
      val runAll: Future[Done] = dequeueResults.runForeach(u => u)
      Await.result(runAll, 20.second)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to understand what you are doing, but it's a bit unclear to me why you would use streams at all if you are only connecting queues? Wouldn't that be easier with just a queue and without streams?

Comment: i am working on a related problem where i am trying to get backpressure to work using Source and Sink queues.   eventually the queues i am experimenting with here will be used in a more complex flow (that's the idea).